# Generating artificial time series data

Tags: python, time-series

can anyone please offer suggestions on ways to programmatically generate time series data artificially. if possible, mimic the distribution of an existing dataset (say hourly humidity readings) and add some noise if required. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please check this link https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/52628/73441.

Comment: Please check my answer to this related question: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/76159/76955

Answer (score 1):

This article is great to generate time series data in python.
Hope this helps.

https://towardsdatascience.com/basic-time-series-manipulation-with-pandas-4432afee64ea

Comment: thanks but the link describes handling time series data not generating time series data..

Comment: This answer is not at all heplful.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
date_rng = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='1/08/2018', freq='H')
```

This is generating a time stamp, hourly data

```
type(date_rng)
```

pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex

Create a dataframe and add random values for the corresponding date

```
df = pd.DataFrame(date_rng, columns=['date'])
df['data'] = np.random.randint(0,100,size=(len(date_rng)))
```

You have your self-generated time-series data.
Hope this one helps.

Comment: He wants to mimic existing data.

Answer (score 0):

TimeGAN is a library in python which can help you achieve this task

There is a nice article to do it in details
https://towardsdatascience.com/modeling-and-generating-time-series-data-using-timegan-29c00804f54d